# How can I find nodes with specific relationships?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I find nodes with specific properties using a Cypher query language? I have a list of cities. List contains city names and countries where those cities are situated. I need to print out the country for one specific city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for this is:

```
MATCH (city:City)-[:IN]-(country:Country)
WHERE city.name = "London"
RETURN country.name;
```

The `MATCH` clause specifies a node and relationship pattern with two connected nodes, labeled `City` and `Country`, connected by a relationship of type `IN`.